# Change NetBeans "DoubleClick Highlighted" Text Background

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

In NetBeans 7.4.0, when I doubleclick certain words in the code, NetBeans highlights all of them (in my case, in yellow).  For the sake of clarity, and hopefully to avoid any kneejerk downvotes, I am not referring to the background color of selected text, or the text on the caret's current row.

[image]

Having recently decided to change the editor's colors (tools --> options, fonts & colors tab), I have been unable to figure out the offical name of this doubleclick highlighting to address it's color.  I have been through the entire list of choices on the syntax, highlighting, annotation, diff, and versioning sub-tabs without finding an entry with a background color that seemed to match the doubleclick highlighting.

How do I change the background color of this doubleclick highlighted text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the thing your looking for is called occurrences and it can be found in the path:

tools -> options -> fonts&color -> syntax

except it's not in all of the languages, try highlighting the specific language you want this to be a different color in and then you should have the option to change "Mark Occurrences"

Comment: Ahhh!  I had failed to specifically select Java.  Thank you.